# how the code '-input[range(target.shape[0]),target]' works?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm learing pytorch.Reading the official tutorial,I met the preplexing code.
input is a tensor, so is target.

```
def nll(input,target):
    return -input[range(target.shape[0]),target].mean()
```

And the pred is:
[image: pred]

target is:
[image: target]

the '-input[range(target.shape[0]),target]' is:
[image: 'input[range(target.shape[0],target]']

Output shows this is not substracting target from input or merging two tensors

Comment: please do not post screenshots of tensors/logs/code - copy-paste the relevant text and format it accordingly.

Comment: much of the code in the question is not essential to the question. consider making a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `input[range(target.shape[0]), target]` simply picks, from each row `i` of `input` the element at column indicated by the corresponding element of `target`, that is `target[i]`.
In other words, if `out = input[range(target.shape[0]), target]` then `out[i] = input[i, target[i]]`.

This is very similar to [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar code somewhere and I was curious as to how it works:

My thought:
I think it follows general rule of slicing.

-input for example = 64,10 # 64 different outputs with 10 individual probabilities

-`target` = 64  # 64 targets for 64 samples, bunch of indexes

-input[row,col] ~ input[range(64), target]

-the range(64) ensures all the rows are considered while the target picks the column index of each row.

-That said, it is a smart way of writing cross-enrtropy code since all you care is the probab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).